# Static footer with dynamic content

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a custom design for a website that consists of an image as the background, and a box that has the content. [The website design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFDDf.jpg)

So my [problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UImzC.png) that I have a page that has a set of accordion buttons that expand the content larger than the container. I want the container to stay the same size and have the content overflow it.

---

The relevant code is as follows:

**CSS**

```
.background {
    background-image: url(/recources/images/page-background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 98px;
}

.web-content {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.web-content_row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.web-content_row .web-content_height {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body class="background">
  <section class="web-content">
    <div class="web-content_row web-content_height">
      <header>
        <!-- Header content -->
      </header>

      <section class="web-content_tutorials-menu">
        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <!-- Footer content -->
    </footer>
  </section>
</body>
```

---

Whenever an accordion button is clicked, the content pushes the footer and the container box off the page, and this has several issues for me. First I don't want the container to expand with the content, I want the content to overflow the container and the container to stay the same size. Second, once the content is larger the view height the scroll-bar doesn't show up.

Now I did try really hard to figure this out on my own before asking this question. And I also have a few theories on what is wrong. I think the page won't scroll is because of the `display: table;` and `display: table-row;` properties in the CSS code.

So if any of you guys have an answer that can fix the content expanding both the footer and the container would be awesome.

Sorry if this explanation was too "in depth". This website has a very custom design that has a lot of differences than most normal websites.

Sincerely,
Hexsphere

Comment: What element is the one with a white background color ? The code you provided seems incomplete.

Comment: @3Dos I used all the relevant code for the structure of the code. But if there is any code you think I missed I'll check it out.

Comment: But to answer your question, the `.web-content` element is the one with the white background. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it keeping your HTML structure :

```css
body {
  background: tomato; /* Simulates the photo background */
}

.web-content {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10vh; /* change accordingly to your wishes */
  width: 80vw;
  background: aqua; /* oh yeah I like wicked colors */
  left: 10vw; /* (100 - 80) / 2 */
  bottom: 15vh; /* (100 - 70) / 2 */
}
```

```html
<body class="background">
  <section class="web-content">
    <div class="web-content_row web-content_height">
      <header>
        <!-- Header content -->
      </header>

      <section class="web-content_tutorials-menu">
        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        </div>

        <button class="accordion-button">Title</button>
        <div class="panel">
        foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>bar<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>bar<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>bar<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>bar<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>bar<br>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <!-- Footer content -->
    Fixed footer heehaa
  </footer>
</body>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like it would work, but the content expands when the `title` buttons are clicked. One other thing is that I forgot to add some CSS code for the background. xD

Comment: That's why I put the foo bar elements to simulate an overflow... This should work. Please try it and experiment !

Comment: I tried it, with 100% success on the container overflow part. But, the footer won't go to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do you want me to give you a fiddle of all the code?

Comment: I edited my post but I strongly suggest you search and try and learn CSS before asking others to code for you! There are tons of tutorials and documentations out there, don't be afraid to read them

Comment: Look, I'm not your average dev who hardly knows web development. I just am experiencing an issue that's beyond the average website, because of the fact I have a container that's smaller than the browser view size.

Comment: And all the tutorials I found had legit methods for a site using the full view size. So I'd really appreciate it if you could help me because I've tried almost everything I can do to make my UX look as sleek as possible. :)